# Function in Anchor tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a couple functions:

```
function Toggle(id)
{
   EToggle(document.getElementById(id));
}

function EToggle(element)
{
   var subject = element.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
   if(subject.style.display == "none")
   {
      subject.style.display = "block";
   }
   else
   {
      subject.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

The Toggle function is called upon load, and works fine.  However, when I say 
 `<a href="javascript:Toggle(flat)">`, nothing happens.

So the question is, why doesn't it work in the link, but on the page load?

If you need more details, [here](http://s1547.mtchs.org/Boise%20Concrete%20Sawing%20Company/services.html) is my website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
<a href="javascript:Toggle('flat')">
```

instead of

```
<a href="javascript:Toggle(flat)">
```

Comment: You are really going to smash my head in because of automatic formatting?  That line break wasn't there intentionally.

Comment: @Jack It's less about the line break and more about the string.  Unless flat is a function of yours which returns a value...

Comment: @Jack: the difference isn't the line break, it's the quotes around `flat`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use single quotes around the id-strings in the html, as Matei mentioned.

Next, change line 31 of collapsible.js

You're asking for the first div contained by the clicked element. The problem is, your <a> tag itself doesn't have any. You're after the div that *follows* the <a> So, you want to get the parent node's div elements.

```
var subject = element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
```

Remember, your structure is like this:

```
<div class="collapsible" id="demo">
    <a href="javascript:Toggle('demo')"><h1>Demolition and Removal</h1></a>
    <div style="display: none; ">
        <p>Content removed from here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight and sincerity, I appreciate it.
However, note that the "element" value is the div tag, not the anchor tag.  Thus, the parentNode change would break the code.